# Oracle DB Developer error on importing .dmp

Tags: oracle, import, datapump

Trying to open a .dmp I've been sent.  I get the following errors from the Import Wizard on Oracle SQL Developer.

[image: Error log]

Any thoughts on what my problem might be?  I have set full file/folder permissions on Linux and otherwise think I'm using standard boilerplate code...

Comment: *" I have set full file/folder permissions on Linux "* - Ah yes, but have you created an Oracle directory object for the directory where the .dmp file is? Have you specified a different directory for the `logfile` destination?

Comment: as in `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY my_import_folder AS '/home/folder-with-the-dmp-file' ?  If so, yes.  If not, no -- what should I do?

Comment: The logfile is set to write in the same directory as the .dmp file

Comment: And the `oracle` **OS user** has read and write permissions on that directory?

Comment: Not sure -- I'm admin on a VM that I specifically created to run Oracle SQL Developer, where I am (obviously) also admin.  Is there a command I need to run in oracle? Can I check my status?

Comment: Data pump directories are on the Oracle *server* OS, not the client machine/VM where you are running SQL Developer. (Unless client and server are the same machine, of course). If you created your VM to run SQL Developer it sounds like they are different (though odd to need to do that just for the client).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean -- For framing:  I've been sent a small database (1Gb), and I'm running the VM instanced Oracle on my laptop just to test the database structure.  I have no background in Oracle.

Comment: SQL Developer is a client, and you can initiate an import into an existing database from it; and you must have a DBA connection set up to a database in order to have started the wizard (I think). Is that database on the same VM, or are you connecting to somewhere else? The directory for the dump and log files have to be wherever that database is running, and they have to be accessible by the OS user the Oracle processes are running under - which is usually `oracle`. Having the files under `/home` looks suspicious as directories under that are usually locked down.